# display a div when a radio button is checked, and pass this and trigger on loading into a stage 2 of a form

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm a newbie in JavaScript or jQuery.
Got a task here that I'm totally stumped with.
comes in 2 parts.

1) I need to display an image within my navigation for some tabbed content when a radio button is checked within the content itself.

2) I need to trigger this when the form is loaded at a Stage 2 of the form. i.e. the form is passed from one state to the next. so instead of using onClick as an eventHandler it needs to either work onLoad or trigger the onClick when the form loads again.

Hope this makes sense?!?!

Thanks in advance.

```
<li><a id="tab1">Language 1</a><div class="selected"><img src="image.jpg"></div></li><li><a id="tab2">Language 2</a><div class="selected"><img src="image.jpg"></div></li><li><a id="tab3">Language 3</a><div class="selected"><img src="image.jpg"></div></li><li><a id="tab4">Language 4</a><div class="selected"><img src="image.jpg"></div></li><li><a id="tab5">Language 5</a><div class="selected"><img src="image.jpg"></div></li>

<input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" />Yes <input  class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="no" />No</br><input  class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio2" value="yes" />Yes <input  class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio2" value="no" />No</br><input  class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio3" value="yes" />Yes <input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio3" value="no" />No</br><input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio4" value="yes" />Yes <input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio4" value="no" />No</br><input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio5" value="yes" />Yes <input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radio5" value="no" />No</br>
```

Comment: `Stage 2 of the form ???`

Comment: yeah, so the form is created and saved by one user. then it's picked up by a second user at 'Stage 2'

Comment: `form is created and saved by one user`??.Not very clear

Comment: ok it's difficult to put into words.
let's try it like this.
creator opens the form makes amends and saves the form. Once it's saved it's opened by a second user who can look at the form and see the info input by the creator. 
If the radio button has been checked in the tabbed content then there should be some way of displaying that it's been checked to the second user.

Comment: does that make some sense?!?! sorry :-)

Comment: radio buttons use name to toggle but having multiple elements with the same id is not proper html.

Comment: oops Ok I've amended the code in the question

Comment: @user2194969 simple question how are your storing form state?

Comment: @user2194969 simple question but not such a simple answer :-)
why do you ask?